# Need some help getting these videos to resize correctly

Tags: css

I am using a plugin to show my videos in RSS. I am using a new theme that is responsive and it requires the media settings in Wordpress to stay at 9999 height and 580 width. As you can see from this link, it is stretching my videos WAY long. I really need to get this fixed as I have almost 200 videos on my site that look like this now. I'm sure there is a way to fix this with CSS. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Here is the link: http://noahsdad.com/exercise-ball/

Comment: 9999 height seems a bit excessive.  Are you sure they're not talking about the z-index being 9999?  That makes more sense as that high a z-index would place it on top of everything else.

Comment: I think it's has something to do with the media settings and the responsive theme. Typically you leave the height blank and just add the width. However for some reason this plug in is actually resizing it to 9999 high. Im assuming there is some CSS you can use to just set it different. Also I can't change the media settings to anything other than 9999 high, so I have to find a work around. As you can see the videos on the front page of my site are working and sizeing well. (they do not use the plug in)

Comment: Its your vimeo iFrame that is getting set to 9999px high. Probably the best approach would be to use javaScript to adjust the height attribute of the iframe to something more sane.

Comment: Is there a way to use some css (or the php in the plug in) so that only videos that use that plug in, are resized to use 320 height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the fact that the plugin is setting the height as an **attribute** rather than an **inline style**, this simple CSS rule should fix the problem `iframe[height="9999"] { height: 320px; }`. I assumed that by `320` you meant `320px`.

Comment: Thanks, and you are correct, I meant 320 px. But the issue is there are other iframe videos that are using iframes that are not from that plug in. Will this code mess with those? (The video on the home page of our website is not using that plug in if you want to check it out. Thanks. :)

Comment: It won't mess with other iframes, don't worry. The CSS rule I wrote above says "pick every iframe where the height attribute is equal to 9999 and set its height to 320px". The iframes who aren't using the plugin don't have a height attribute set to 9999, so the rule won't affect them.